# Once obtained the results

Tags: word-order

Is "Once obtained the results" correct in English??

I mean, is it an equivalent, alternate way to say "Once the results have/had been obtained"?

For instance, "Once obtained the results, they will be analised".

Comment: I'm a native speaker and I've always interpreted it this way, correct or otherwise.  I ask myself if the subject is somehow implied, but I don't think so.  This reads fine without context, assuming it is followed up by a sentence which explains how these results are used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not correct. If you wanted to be terse, you could say:

> Once obtained, the results will be analysed.

But if your first part of the sentence uses *the results* as an object, a subject is required:

> Once **I've** obtained the results, they will be analysed.

Comment: And you could also say "Once **the results have been obtained**, they will be analysed."